# FormData key does not go through

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I use external class for making object variable into FormData variable. All of the keys go through, all but One for File object.

Here is that external class: https://github.com/therealparmesh/object-to-formdata

This is how I create objects and make them into FormData

```
var _documents = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfFiles.length; i++) {

  var document = {
     File: arrayOfFiles[i].file.nativeFile,
     DocumentId: arrayOfFiles[i].documentId,
     DocumentType: arrayOfFiles[i].documentName
  };

  _documents.push(document);
}

var uploadedInformation = {
       LoanID: 1452465,
       documents: _documents
};

var options = {
   indices: true,
   nulls: true
};

var a = objectToFormData(uploadedInformation, options);

for (var pair of a.entries()) {
     console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
}

jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url:  '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Home")',
    data: a
});
```

Code for controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
        [ActionName("UploadFile")]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(UploadedInformation uploadedInformation)
        {
            _ = Request.Form;
            return View();
        }
```

UploadedFile class:

```cs
public class UploadedInformation
    {

        public long LoanID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Document> Documents { get; set; }

    }
```

Document class:

```cs
public class Document
{

      public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set;}
      public string DocumentId { get; set;}
      public string DocumentType { get; set; }
}
```

All of the items bind perfectly, except for `File`.
In browser debugger keys and values are:

```
LoanID, 1452465
documents[0][File], [object File]
documents[0][DocumentId], 1
documents[0][DocumentType], Passport
```

`_=Request.Form` also displays only 3 keys without `documents[0][File]`

**Update:**
I changed controller to

```cs
public ActionResult UploadFile(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file, IEnumerable<string> documentType, IEnumerable<string>documentId, long loanId){...}
```

and `_=Request.Form` still shows nothing with `file`, however file list is populated

**Another update:**
Apparently, this time file items shows only in `_=Request.File`

Comment: How is the File being sent?  the [object File] part does not tell us much as that seems to just be the console logging output, so the object won't output to string. Are you able to get the raw HTTP request that is being posted (if using Chrome, open dev tools and go to the 'Network' section)?

Comment: @StevieW The Form Data tab says: "LoanID: 1452465
documents[0][File]: (binary)
documents[0][DocumentId]: 1
documents[0][DocumentType]: Passport"

Comment: @StevieW I did an update

Comment: If the network request is showing the field name and the (binary) indicator then it is being submitted.   Have you tried checking Request.Files to see if the incoming request has registered the files in a manner different to what you are expecting?

Comment: @StevieW I have written some updates. Yes, it appears Request.File has the keys, however they still not bind. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way that the controller is handling the file upload parts of the request, I suspect you may need to make some adjustments to your process and allow for the fact that the files are being separated from the main object.

I've included some adjustments to your code below (note, this is untested so you may need to experiment a little), assuming that the files come through in the same order as you Documents, then just run a match up process before running your own process.

Code for controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
        [ActionName("UploadFile")]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(List<HttpPostedFileBase> myFiles, UploadedInformation uploadedInformation)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <uploadedInformation.Documents.Length; i++)
            {
                uploadedInformation.Documents[i].File = myFiles[i];
            }

            // Do stuff

            return View();
        }
```

In the event that the order of the files cannot be assumed, you can add the filename to the data to aid with matching on the server side

Javascript

```
var _documents = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfFiles.length; i++) {

  var document = {
     File: arrayOfFiles[i].file.nativeFile,
     FileName: arrayOfFiles[i].file.name,
     DocumentId: arrayOfFiles[i].documentId,
     DocumentType: arrayOfFiles[i].documentName
  };

  _documents.push(document);
}
```

Comment: So, basically, to separate file upload and then just attach it manually in the controller by id or filename? To be honest, I was thinking about this solution, but wanted to avoid as much as possible, because, as I see it, it creates opportunities for errors, but I will probably implement it if I can't find how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it.   by mapping the HttpPostedFileBase object into the model it should allow the rest of your process to work without further changes

Comment: Yeah, seams reasonable enough